# Переменная ссылается на саму себя

Tags: php

Прочитал я достаточно много статей о том как устроены переменные внутри машины Zend и узнал одну интересную вещь, которую не могу объяснить:

```
$int = 100;
xdebug_debug_zval('int');/// int:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 100
$int = &$int;
xdebug_debug_zval('int');/// int:(refcount=1, is_ref=1),int 100
```

Как получается так что мы создаем ссылку саму на себя? Как это вообще возможно?
Подобного не видел, если и будете ставить минусы то аргументируйте пожалуйста свой выбор.

**Небольшая информация из того что я знаю:**

Как правило `is_ref=1` только в том случае когда на `zval` контейнер ссылается 2 и более переменные жесткой ссылкой.

`refcount` - это количество переменных ссылающихся на один и тот же `zval` контейнер, но разница в том что `refcount` по разному работает с `is_ref=0` и `is_ref=1`.

Если `is_ref=0`, а `refcount > 1` то при создании жестких ссылок создается новый `zval`  контейнер, если мы делаем присвоение по значению то новый `zval` не создается, а используется старый.

Если `is_ref=1`, а `refcount > 1` то при создании жестких ссылок новый `zval` не создается, а используется старый, но если мы не создаем жесткую ссылку, а присваиваем по значению то создается новый `zval` контейнер.

P.S Я написал это для того, чтобы показать что прекрасно понимаю, что я спрашиваю, а также показываю почему мне непонятно поведение кода, которое я написал выше.

**P.S Феерично**

> **Отметим, что если "refcount" равен 1, то "is_ref" будет всегда равен
>   FALSE.**
>   **http://php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47503/discussion-on-question-by-maximpro-----).

Answer (score 1):

Внутри структуры `zval` не хранится имя символа, который отсылает к ней. Это легко увидеть из [определения `zval`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php). Сам символ (имя переменной) хранится отдельно в символьной таблице.

Таким образом то, какие флаги отмечены внутри `zval`, и то, как вы её называете - разные сущности. Название (символ) для переменной - это одно. Что хранится внутри переменной, включая всевозможные флаги - это другое.

Благодаря этому может быть много переменных имеющих одно и то же имя. Например, может быть внешняя относительно функции переменная `$int`, имеющая одно значения, и может быть внутренняя для функции переменная `$int`, имеющая как другое значение, так и может быть одноименная переменная ссылающаяся на то же самое значение что и ранее упомянутая переменная `$int`.

Это реализуется в виде символьных таблиц соответствия символов и значений `zval` для каждой области видимости.

В вашем примере первый символ (или имя переменной) `$int` - это не то же самое что второй символ `$int`. Хоть они оба отсылают к одной `zval` в тот момент когда вы на них смотрите, в момент создания первый `$int` был просто числом, а второй - был уже ссылкой. Второй *уже был* ссылкой до того как вы его назвали, присвоив символу `$int`.

Для примера, ниже `$a` и `$b` отличаются от ваших двух `$int` лишь именем, а значит у `zval` в PHP 7 уже будет две ссылки:

```
$a = 100;
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
// a: (refcount=0, is_ref=0)=100

$b = &$a;
xdebug_debug_zval('b');
// b: (refcount=2, is_ref=1)=100

xdebug_debug_zval('a');
//a: (refcount=2, is_ref=1)=100
```

Для сравнения, ваш же вариант в PHP 7:

```
$int = 100;
xdebug_debug_zval('int');
// int: (refcount=0, is_ref=0)=100

$int = &$int;
xdebug_debug_zval('int');
//int: (refcount=1, is_ref=1)=100
```

Очевидно, в PHP 7 несколько иное отношение к исходному значению `refcount` для простейших. Для объектов всё как было:

```
$int = new stdClass();
xdebug_debug_zval('int');
// int: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=class stdClass {  }

$int = &$int;
xdebug_debug_zval('int');
// int: (refcount=1, is_ref=1)=class stdClass {  }
```

Comment: Если честно я ничего не понял!

Comment: Мне нужно объяснение для php 5.6, а ваше объяснение для более новой версии

Comment: Простите, но где у вас в вопросе написано что вам нужно объяснение для PHP 5.6? Вы ссылаетесь на документацию для PHP 7, а тесты запускаете в другой версии. Может быть в этом проблема?

Comment: С чего вы взяли что я ссылаюсь на документацию PHP 7.0? Там как раз написано для старой версии!

Comment: Я знаю что есть такое понятие как символьная таблица переменных и для каждой области видимости она своя, поэтому одинаковые имена переменных не конфликтуют между собой(по символьной таблице тоже есть вопросы, они тоже касаются этой же темы, но задам я позже). Но ведь в моем примере одна и та же область видимости. Мне не очень понятно когда вы написали 5ый абзац сверху(Как это первый int это число, а второй ссылка?Я понимаю что есть тип данных integer, но тип данных ссылка нет)
P.S ИМХО лично я не вижу отличий между ссылкой и переменной они все равно указывают на один и тот же zval контейнер

Comment: Это в самом zval хранится информация о количестве переменных ссылающихся на этот контейнер (refcount) и булево значение которое говорит о том является ли данная коллекция переменных жесткими ссылками (is_ref) (увы пришлось так сказать =)). Я думаю вы меня поняли
P.S Вашу ссылку я кстати до этого не читал и очень странно что нет перевода такое ощущение что никто этим не интересуется

Comment: Что ж вам непонятно-то если вы все понимаете? =)

Comment: Так мне не понятно почему php меняет флаг на `is_ref=1` когда идет ссылка на саму себя =) В мане как я процитировал можно увидеть слова что: `Отметим, что если "refcount" равен 1, то "is_ref" будет всегда равен FALSE.` - то есть 0. Тут я и запутался...~~~~

Comment: Кстати про символьную таблицу: Так ли что ключ это имя переменной, а значение это указатель на контейнер (именно указатель как в С)? Что будет если мы напишем `$a = 10; $a = $a;`? В таблице переменных будет перезаписано имя или оно останется? А если так: `$a = 10; $a = &$a;`? В этом случае перезапишется имя в таблице переменных или нет? Меня вот такие моменты интересуют, а такого я нигде не видел.
P.S `zval`'ы `zval`'ами, а вот строение и работу символьной таблицы интересно бы посмотреть =)

Comment: Например потому что сначала срабатывает оператор `&`, создавая ссылку, и потом только работает оператор присвоения. [См. например здесь байт-код для девятой строки.](https://3v4l.org/RGENJ/vld#output)

Comment: Ну тогда это объясняет изменение `is_ref` несмотря на то какую переменную вы привязываем =)
Кстати это не байт, это оп-код.
И да есть ли какая-нибудь информация насчет того как работает символьная таблица? Оп-коды этого не показывают!

Comment: @MaximPro это достойно отдельного вопроса. Задавайте вопрос, назначайте награду - посмотрим на ответы.

Comment: Я боюсь что никто не ответит =) Но я задам вопрос ок =)

Comment: Здесь в комментариях точно никто не ответ. Особенно когда награда была обещана и не получена =)

Comment: А смысл от этих очков? Мне они нужны чисто для конкурсов чтобы привлечь внимание, а те кто копят их я не понимаю =)